# How can I show a 170mb image in a webpage?

Tags: php, html, css, image

So I have this big image that's 170mb, 13312x13312px that I want to show in a webpage, as efficiently as possible so people don't have to wait 50 hours to actually see the image. I'm very new to making webpages so I would appreciate a simple solution (if there's one). Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're probably going to need a solution that "tiles" the image, i.e. load smaller chunks of it from the server (so you would have to prepare those upfront) and display them next to each other. If the user scrolls in any direction, then you load & position the next set of chunks that need to appear in that direction. And you might even need to hide chunks that get scrolled out of view again, so as to not over-tax the browsers memory with all the unpacked image data.

Comment: The 170mb image _file_ size are the less relevant metric here. The browser will have to hold the decoded, uncompressed image data in memory - and even if we assume only RGB without an alpha component, that is 13312x13312x3 bytes here, or ... 507 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Since im not 100% sure from your question I would like to ask: Does your image have to be displayed in 13312x13312px?

The most common and simplest/quickest way would be, to simply not output the 170mb image, but rather cut it down in terms of dimensions and compress it in photoshop and then display that image.

A 3840px width image for example would be sufficient to even be displayed nicely on 4k screens - 1920px width for a "normal" Full-HD screen.

This process could even be automated server side with Imagick or GD in PHP.

Alternatively look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: The image is a map from Minecraft, every pixel represents 1 block in game. It would be great to be able to see every pixel when you zoom in or want detail in a specific size.